# Suitable platform for developing browser based database application (reporting) with SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ruby-on-rails, reporting-services, ubuntu

I need to develop a dynamic web page retrieve data from a stored procedure on a SQL Server.

Considering the licensing issue, development resources, security and maintainability, can someone suggest a suitable platform for this project?

I have a Ubuntu server running Drupal and also a Windows Server 2003 running SQL Server 2000 and IIS for FTP server only.

Is ASP.NET and Reporting Service the natural choice? What are my other options? Ruby On Rails? Since the SQL Server on the server is mission critical and I don't feel very comfortable asking anymore from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS is very good for the price; though in SQL 2000 its a bit limited - especially for charting. If you have a small budget you could write nice looking reports using stored procedures and something like [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx) reporting if you want to do a bit more of the work on the web server. There is a trial version  you could use for a quick prototype to see how it fits in; but it works very nicely with asp.net development and is nicely integrated with Visual Studio.